# Can we add snippets in Page Layout?

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout

I have two questions.

- Can we add snippets like Main Navigation, Current Navigation etc. in Page Layout or they can only be added in Master Page?
- You know there are two items in top menu above in Sharepoint 2013 (just besides that blue bar). One item display the name of user currently logged in and if you click on it, it displays links About Me, Sign Out and Perzonalize this Page. Similarly next item shows a GEAR icon and when you click on it, it shows Show Ribbon, Shared With, Edit Page etc.
  I want to display these items with drop down menu at some other location on page, how can I do that? I know how to hide this whole bar which is very easy to do but I don't know how to display this menu at some other location. Is there a snippet for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reposition it wherever you would like it using CSS.

```
<span class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd">
```

I think this is the container for the item you are referring to so you could apply CSS to this id which repositions it. eg:

```
#siteactiontd {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about point 1 i.e. can I add snippets in page layout?

Comment: I mean to say adding Current Navigation snippet in page layout.

Comment: Not sure about 2013 but you can certain add current navigation in page layouts in 2010.